# mongod.service remains in "Active: activating (start)" and never reaches "Active: active (running)

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, systemctl

my mongod.service on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS with Mongo 6.0.8 never reaches "Active: active (running)" and remains in "Active: activating (start)". The **mongod instance is up and running fine**! But as the service never reaches the active state, **other services which rely on an active mongod.service are not starting**...

- How can I fix that?

I have tried already couple of things - including reinstalling mongodb, but everything gave me the same behavior: When I `sudo systemctl start mongod.service` the command is haning. When I exit the command with `ctrl+c` and `sudo systemctl status --full --lines=50 mongod.service` I get following output:

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mongod.service.d
└─mongod.conf
Active: activating (start) since Sat 2023-08-12 01:39:29 CEST; 13s ago
Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
Main PID: 3002149 (mongod)
Memory: 166.3M
CGroup: /system.slice/mongod.service
└─3002149 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf

> Aug 12 01:39:29 xxxxx.xxxxxx.net systemd[1]: mongod.service: Trying to enqueue job mongod.service/start/replace
> Aug 12 01:39:29  xxxxx.xxxxxx.net systemd[1]: mongod.service: Installed new job mongod.service/start as 27570
> Aug 12 01:39:29  xxxxx.xxxxxx.net systemd[1]: mongod.service: Enqueued job mongod.service/start as 27570
> Aug 12 01:39:29  xxxxx.xxxxxx.net systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed to set 'blkio.weight' attribute on '/system.slice/mongod.service' to '500': No such file or directory
> Aug 12 01:39:29  xxxxx.xxxxxx.net systemd[1]: mongod.service: Passing 0 fds to service
> Aug 12 01:39:29  xxxxx.xxxxxx.net systemd[1]: mongod.service: About to execute: /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
> Aug 12 01:39:29  xxxxx.xxxxxx.net systemd[1]: mongod.service: Forked /usr/bin/mongod as 3002149
> Aug 12 01:39:29  xxxxx.xxxxxx.net systemd[1]: mongod.service: Changed dead -> start
> Aug 12 01:39:29  xxxxx.xxxxxx.net systemd[1]: Starting MongoDB Database Server...
> Aug 12 01:39:29  xxxxx.xxxxxx.net systemd[1]: mongod.service: User lookup succeeded: uid=111 gid=113
> Aug 12 01:39:29  xxxxx.xxxxxx.net systemd[3002149]: mongod.service: Executing: /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
> Aug 12 01:39:29  xxxxx.xxxxxx.net mongod[3002149]: {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-11T23:39:29.560Z"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":7484500, "ctx":"-","msg":"Environment variable MONGODB_CONFIG_OVERRIDE_NOFORK == 1, overriding \"processManagement.fork\" to false"}
```

This is my mongod.service `sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=MongoDB Database Server
Documentation=https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
User=mongodb
Group=mongodb
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/mongod
Environment="MONGODB_CONFIG_OVERRIDE_NOFORK=1"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
RuntimeDirectory=mongodb
# file size
LimitFSIZE=infinity
# cpu time
LimitCPU=infinity
# virtual memory size
LimitAS=infinity
# open files
LimitNOFILE=64000
# processes/threads
LimitNPROC=64000
# locked memory
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
# total threads (user+kernel)
TasksMax=infinity
TasksAccounting=false

# Recommended limits for mongod as specified in
# https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/ulimit/#recommended-ulimit-settings

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here is my config `nano /etc/mongod.conf`- pretty much default, I only changed the dbPath to create a new one...

```bash
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb2
#  journal:
#    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
#  logRotate: rename

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,mongo0.xxxxxxx.com


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:
#  keyFile: /var/lib/mongo-security/keyfile.txt

#operationProfiling:

#replication:
#  replSetName: rs0

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

This is the log:

```
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-12T01:37:45.470+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"in
> comingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-12T01:37:45.471+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-12T01:37:45.474+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpF
> astOpenQueueSize."}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-12T01:37:45.487+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.te
> nantMigrationDonors"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-12T01:37:45.487+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"confi
> g.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-12T01:37:45.487+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"ShardSplitDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantS
> plitDonors"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-12T01:37:45.487+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-12T01:37:45.488+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":2999311,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongodb2","architecture":"64-bit"
> ,"host":"xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.net"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-12T01:37:45.488+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"6.0.8","gitVersion":"3d84c0dd4e5d99be0d69003652313e7eaf4cdd74
> ","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2004","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-12T01:37:45.488+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"20.04"}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-12T01:37:45.488+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/etc/mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1,mo
> ngo0.xxxxxxxxx.com","port":27017},"processManagement":{"timeZoneInfo":"/usr/share/zoneinfo"},"storage":{"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongodb2"},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":false,"path":"/var/log/mongodb/mongod.
> log"}}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-12T01:37:45.490+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"/var/lib/mongodb2","storageEngine":"wired
> Tiger"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-12T01:37:45.490+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22297,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine. See http://dochub.mo
> ngodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-12T01:37:45.490+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=31625M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,
> threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,remove=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),builtin_extension_config=(zstd=(compression_level=6)),file_manager=(close_idle_time=600,close_scan_interval=
> 10,close_handle_minimum=2000),statistics_log=(wait=0),json_output=(error,message),verbose=[recovery_progress:1,checkpoint_progress:1,compact_progress:1,backup:0,checkpoint:0,compact:0,evict:0,history_store:0,recovery:0,rt
> s:0,salvage:0,tiered:0,timestamp:0,transaction:0,verify:0,log:0],"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-12T01:37:47.061+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger opened","attr":{"durationMillis":1571}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-12T01:37:47.061+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-12T01:37:47.083+02:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22120,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrest
> ricted","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-12T01:37:47.084+02:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5123300, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"vm.max_map_count is too low","attr":{"currentValue":65530,"recommendedMinimum":102400,"maxConns":51200},"
> tags":["startupWarnings"]}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-12T01:37:47.087+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915702, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Updated wire specification","attr":{"oldSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersi
> on":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true},"newSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersio
> n":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":17,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":17,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-12T01:37:47.087+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5853300, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"current featureCompatibilityVersion value","attr":{"featureCompatibilityVersion":"6.0","context":"startup
> "}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-12T01:37:47.087+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":5071100, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Clearing temp directory"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-12T01:37:47.089+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20536,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Flow Control is enabled on this deployment"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-12T01:37:47.089+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20625,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture","attr":{"dataDirectory":"/var/lib/mongodb2/diagnostic.dat
> a"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-12T01:37:47.097+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":6015317, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Setting new configuration state","attr":{"newState":"ConfigReplicationDisabled","oldState":"ConfigPreStar
> t"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-12T01:37:47.097+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22262,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor starting"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-12T01:37:47.104+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-12T01:37:47.104+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"127.0.0.1"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-12T01:37:47.104+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever find a solution? @Meffe

Answer (score 0):

In your `mongod.service` try to add these lines

```
[Service]
PIDFile=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
Type=forking
```

Don't forget to reload the config `systemctl daemon-reload`

And you may add also lines like these.

```
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongodb:mongodb/var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/lib/mongodb2
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongodb:mongodb/var/lib/mongodb2
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/lib/mongodb2
```

This ensures `dbPath` and `/var/run/mongodb` are existing when mongod starts.

`dbPath` is often missing and for `/var/run/mongodb` see https://serverfault.com/questions/74796/directory-in-var-run-gets-deleted-after-hard-reboot

In your `mongod.conf` file use

```
processManagement:
  fork: true
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo
```

Comment: I have added forking and PIDfile to the mongod.service and excluded #Environment="MONGODB_CONFIG_OVERRIDE_NOFORK=1" (while this was set by mongod - maybe because of ubuntu 20 ?)

I have added fork and pidFilePath to the mongod.conf and the result is the same: activating (start) ....